# Pyinstaller with Jenkins for executable file in Raspberry PI

Tags: python, jenkins, pyinstaller, raspberry-pi4

I use Jenkins-pipeline with Docker `image 'python:3.11'` on `5.10.0-23-cloud-amd64` Linux for create an executable file with **Pyinstaller**.

Build command: `pyinstaller --onefile main.py`

After I tried to download and run the created file on OTHER Linux systems, I haven't got any problem but in Raspberry PI 4 I can get this error:

> -bash: ./main: binary is not executable: invalid file format

Pi OS: `Linux raspberrypi 6.1.0-rpi4-rpi-v8 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.1.54-1+rpt2 (2023-10-05) aarch64 GNU/Linux`

What could be causing the problem?

I try to change the Python version, create build with manually.

Comment: Rpi is arm64 not amd64, probably this: https://hub.docker.com/r/arm64v8/python/

Comment: Thanks but if I understand correctly, I can't run arm64 container on amd64 Linux because I can get this error in Jenkins: docker pull arm64v8/python:3; no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries

Comment: Can you build it on your Pi4?, or use the --platform option (https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/), you'll need to install arm64 build tools and dev libraries. An other option is to use the Quemu emulator - https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/target-arm.html In a previous job I tested rpi containers on a linux amd64 system using quemu, but the code was low level c-code.

Comment: Yes, I can build manually on Pi4 and it worked. Maybe I create a Jenkins agent in a Pi4 and use it for CI/CD. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run your software for multiple platforms, you'll have to compile it for each platform separately. As noted in the [Pyinstaller documentation](https://pyinstaller.org/en/v6.1.0/usage.html?highlight=platform#supporting-multiple-operating-systems):

> If you need to distribute your application for more than one OS, for example both Windows and macOS, you must install PyInstaller on each platform and bundle your app separately on each.

This also applies for installs on different platforms, such as different CPU architectures. Notably, the Raspberry Pi 4 uses an ARM-based CPU architecture, so software compiled for other CPU architectures will not work on the Raspberry Pi 4. You will need to compile the software (run pyinstaller) in an ARM-based environment in order to run the compiled software on ARM-based platforms. Most likely, you have compiled the software on an AMD64 computer.

---

Since you mentioned that you're building in Docker, you can probably just use Docker's ARM platform emulation to accomplish this. For example, in your dockerfile, you may do:

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm64 python:3.11
# ...
```

Or you can omit the `--platform` argument and set the environment variable `DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM` to control the platform used by docker.

For example, you might build two images, one for each platform, doing something like this:

```bash
DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64 docker build ...

DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/arm64 docker build ...
```

You can also look into building [multi-platform images](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/) with `docker buildx` to inline building of multiple platforms:

```bash
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 ...
```

Alternatively you can also just run `pyinstaller` on a native ARM64 system (or an emulated system with ARM64), like perhaps directly on your Raspberry Pi. The pyinstaller docs also offer some virtualization suggestions.